# xCode 8.1 GLFWWindow "first responder" Issue

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, glfw

I have recently been working with OpenGL and have decided to use C++ for my latest project with OpenGL. I am using xCode 8.1 with my library paths and header paths linked correctly. Everything compiles fine but i get this error at runtime:

```
2016-11-03 15:17:24.649264 Modulo[25303:14858638] [General] ERROR: Setting <GLFWContentView: 0x100343da0> as the first responder for window <GLFWWindow: 0x100222540>, but it is in a different window ((null))! This would eventually crash when the view is freed. The first responder will be set to nil.(
0   AppKit                              0x00007fff85c069a4 -[NSWindow _validateFirstResponder:] + 566
1   AppKit                              0x00007fff853f79eb -[NSWindow _setFirstResponder:] + 31
2   AppKit                              0x00007fff8549f66a -[NSWindow _realMakeFirstResponder:] + 406
3   AppKit                              0x00007fff8549f480 -[NSWindow makeFirstResponder:] + 123
4   libglfw3.3.dylib                    0x000000010011194a _glfwPlatformCreateWindow + 610
5   libglfw3.3.dylib                    0x000000010010d533 glfwCreateWindow + 428
6   Modulo                              0x00000001000010a8 main + 296
7   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff9c828255 start + 1
8   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1)
```

The code I run to generate this error is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //Engine Startup.
    std::cout << "<----- Engine Start-Up ----->" << std::endl;
    //Initialize GLFW.
    if(!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout << "- GLFW Failed to Initialize!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "+ GLFW Initialized!" << std::endl;
    //Create GLFWWindow
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Engine", nullptr, nullptr);
    if(!window) {
        std::cout << "- GLFWWindow Failed to Create!" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "+ GLFWWindow Created!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program performs as it should but this error could become an issue later and also makes the console hard to debug so I would like to try and sort it out early!

Thank you in advance and if any more information is needed please let me know! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a beginner and I also faced this issue.

I got an error but succeed to create window. How about adding:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

before `glfwCreateWindow`?

Answer (score 1):

Note discussion here [GLFW first responder error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146121/glfw-first-responder-error) which indicates it is a known bug in macOS Sierra, which has been addressed in the git repo for GLFW, but not yet released.