# Shader compilation issue on Mac Mojave using Xcode and Eclipse

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glfw, glew

The following code works fine on a Windows PC using Visual Studio, but fails to provide color to the triangles when running on a Mac.  It seems that the fragment shader compiles without issue, but there is something about the way MacOS is compiling/using the shader that is not working.

I originally started with Xcode.  After discovering that the code runs on a Windows PC, I then switched to Eclipse on the Mac.  Same issue.  No doubt I have a dependency problem, but I'm struggling to find it.

Using MacBook Air with Mojave 10.14.1.  Xcode is 10.1(10861).  Eclipse is 2018-09 (4.9.0).

GLFW is version 3.2.1.  GLEW is 2.1.0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

const GLint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

// Draw primative(s)
void draw() {

    GLenum mode = GL_TRIANGLES;
    GLint first = 0;
    GLsizei count = 6;

    glDrawArrays(mode, first, count);

}

// Create and compile shaders
static GLuint CompileShader(const std::string& source, GLuint shaderType) {

    // Create shader object
    GLuint shaderID = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    const char* src = source.c_str();

    // Attach source code to shader object
    glShaderSource(shaderID, 1, &src, nullptr);

    // Compile shader
    std::cout << "Compiling shader..." << std::endl;
    glCompileShader(shaderID);

    // Return ID of compiled shader
    return shaderID;
}

// Create program object
static GLuint CreateShaderProgram(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader) {

    // Compile vertex shader
    std::cout << "***** Compiling Vertex Shader *****" << std::endl;
    GLuint vertexShaderComp = CompileShader(vertexShader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    // Compile fragment shader
    std::cout << "***** Compiling Fragment Shader *****" << std::endl;
    GLuint fragmentShaderComp = CompileShader(fragmentShader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Create program object
    std::cout << "***** Create program object *****" << std::endl;
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    // Attach vertex and fragment shaders to program object
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShaderComp);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShaderComp);
    std::cout << "***** Attached both Shaders *****" << std::endl;

    // Link shaders to create executable
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Delete compiled shaders
    glDeleteShader(vertexShaderComp);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderComp);

    // Return shaderProgram
    return shaderProgram;

}


int main() {

    glfwInit();  // Initialize the glfw library

    // Setup properties for the window
    // THESE OPTIONS CAUSED THE TRIANGLE TO FAIL RENDERING; NOT SURE WHY
    /*glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);*/

    // Create instance of the window
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Kevin Tooley", nullptr, nullptr);

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);

    // Handle the case that the window was not initialized
    if ( nullptr == window ) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create OpenGL Window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );  // Make the window active

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    // Handle the case where glew failed to init
    if ( GLEW_OK != glewInit() ) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;

        return -1;
    }

    // Parameters used to display the window in relation to my screen
    glViewport( 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight );

    GLfloat vertices[] = {

        // Triangle 1
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, // vert 0
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, // Red

        -0.5, 0.0, 0.0, // vert 1
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, // Green

        -0.5, 0.5, 0.0, // vert2
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, // Blue

        // Triangle 2
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, // vert 0
        1.0, 1.0, 0.0, // Red

        0.5, 0.0, 0.0, // vert 1
        0.0, 1.0, 1.0, // Green

        0.5, -0.5, 0.0, // vert2
        1.0, 0.0, 1.0 // Blue

    };

    GLuint VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);  // Create VBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);  // Select buffer ( VBO )
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);  // Load vertex attributes

    // Specify location and layout to GPU
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    // Vertex Shader source code
    std::string vertexShaderSource =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vec4 aPosition;\n"
    "layout(location = 1) in vec4 aColor;\n"
    "out vec4 oColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_Position = aPosition;\n"
    "oColor = aColor;\n"
    "}\n";

    // Fragment shader source code
    std::string fragmentShaderSource =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "in vec4 oColor;\n"
    "out vec4 fragColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "fragColor = oColor;\n"
    "}\n";


    // Create shader program
    GLuint shaderProgram = CreateShaderProgram(vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource);

    // Use shader program
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Loop to process while window is open
    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) ) {

        glfwPollEvents();

        // Resize window and drawing simultaneously
        //glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);
        //glViewport( 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight );

        //glClearColor( 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f );
        //glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        // Draw primative
        draw();

        //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        glfwSwapBuffers( window );

        //glfwPollEvents();

    }

    // The window has been closed, so terminate glfw
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;

}
```

The console output is as follows.  Note the error at the beginning.  According to this point it is known bug?  [GLFW first responder error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146121/glfw-first-responder-error)

```
2018-11-19 22:04:14.669523-0500 GLFW OpenGL[30749:3605032] [General] ERROR: Setting <GLFWContentView: 0x1005d0e60> as the first responder for window <GLFWWindow: 0x1005aa770>, but it is in a different window ((null))! This would eventually crash when the view is freed. The first responder will be set to nil.
(
    0   AppKit                              0x00007fff48427a8b -[NSWindow _validateFirstResponder:] + 530
    1   AppKit                              0x00007fff48427835 -[NSWindow _setFirstResponder:] + 31
    2   AppKit                              0x00007fff484fa114 -[NSWindow _realMakeFirstResponder:] + 448
    3   libglfw.3.dylib                     0x00000001003619f7 _glfwPlatformCreateWindow + 644
    4   libglfw.3.dylib                     0x000000010035d71e glfwCreateWindow + 443
    5   GLFW OpenGL                         0x00000001000015bd main + 77
    6   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff7803508d start + 1
)
***** Compiling Vertex Shader *****
Compiling shader...
***** Compiling Fragment Shader *****
Compiling shader...
***** Create program object *****
***** Attached both Shaders *****
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Finally, here is the screen shot of the output on the Mac:

[image: Triangles shown, but they have no color]

I don't have a screen shot for the PC, but it works without issue.

Comment: OSX doesn't need GLEW. While it may work, somehow, I prefer to enclose all of GLEW code inside `#ifndef __APPLE__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shaders are setup to use OpenGL 3.3 Core profile but you do not specify the version in the GLFW initialization.  This is probably causing a mismatch between the shaders and the version of OpenGL being initialized.  [Check out this link](https://www.glfw.org/faq.html#41---how-do-i-create-an-opengl-30-context) and specify 3 for both major and minor version.

Also, you might want to check that your shader program compiled with errors.  [Here is an example from the OpenGL wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Example/GLSL_Program_Link_Error_Testing) on how to do that.

If you are still having issues then add [glGetError()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml) after each OpenGL call to nail down where the error is occurring.

Comment: Thank you.  It is true that I had a mismatch.  The problem is that when I add the `glfwWindowHint` major and minor lines, it prevents the triangles from rendering at all.  It's a blank window.  So I think I still have a mismatch, but of a different flavor.

Comment: I added a few more options for you to try in my post.

Comment: Got it!  Your suggestions were very helpful.  glGetError was key.  It turns out that I was getting a 1282 error after calling glEnableVertexAttribArray.  The Core Profile requires a Vertex Array Object (VAO) to be bound for all vertex related calls.  [See this post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643027/opengl-invalid-operation-following-glenablevertexattribarray)

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I would think your `OpenGL-version` is outdated on your Mac. This would cause certain functions to not behave as expected. The OpenGL-version can be obtained with `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`.

Comment: Thank you for that pointer.  printing the result of `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` showed that I was using version 2.1.  The trouble is that when I add in the `glfwWindowHint` for major and minor (both set to 3), it causes the triangle(s) to not render.  It's a blank window.  But doing so does result in using `OpenGL 4.1`.  Just guessing, I also set major to 4 and minor to 1.  No help.